# Unable to install Opera or Tor browser on Ubntu 16.4 lts

Tags: dual-boot, browser

I'm fed up with new Firefox it is "like watching paint dry" to load so have tried to install both Opera & Tor Browser on this  Sony Laptop that I have "dual booted" with win 7 It possibly has non original hard drive, I bought it 2nd/3rd?hand. 
I have read all the questions & answers relevant on this page, none helps. I tried in the terminal but I'm not too confident there,I just copied & pasted commands I saw here but didn't help either. Also deleted one download of Opera & tried again as recommended here. Install in Ubuntu software just will not start. 
Tried Tor Browser directly from Ubuntu software but it will not authenticate/verify?. Say's I'm being targeted "try again", I tried downloading 4 times. Went back to trying with Opera still no go? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: The easiest option is probably to install "Software Boutique" which is from the Ubuntu-MATE project and runs in any *Ubuntu. The Boutique contains lots 'best-of-class' software which includes Tor-Browser, Opera & more. It adds the required PPAs to your system as needed making it easy and allowing software to be auto-updated. The Boutique doesn't list everything (use Ubuntu Software, Synaptic for that...)

Comment: Thanks guiverc I searched for software boutique & downloaded into terminal this: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-welcome which seemed to process but I can't find anything in Ubuntu software? Was that the wrong command? If so can you tell me what to command? Thanks for your help here

Comment: You've grabbed the correct package; it contains a "Welcome to Ubuntu.." app plus the "Software Boutique" app.

Comment: Yes I can see it now, it seems I had/have ubuntu software but needed ubuntu software centre. I now have both, ubuntu  loath to load? Centre is attempting to install Tor now. Ubuntu software is indiacted to try & install Opera but it won't open.

Comment: Opps pressed enter too soon. I will look here tomorrow & give details bedtime here now thanks again guiverc

Comment: FYI, tor and Chromium are in the Ubuntu repos (universe?), even if Opera isn't. The tor browser bundle might best be obtained directly from their site, it updates itself, and I don't know if they have an official PPA so any others might be 2nd hand at best, and possibly delayed

Comment: I agree with @Xen2050 - get the tor bundle from the tor project. Also the new firefox is fast, IMHO

Comment: Hello, I have managed to get Opera operational now but Tor will not install. I'm not sure if it is because of my provider, mirror or location. I am in Ecuador. I can't update an old bitcoin wallet either I believe it is banned here,(another issue, no worries, nothing significant in there). Tor is half installed & tries to load for the first time but them tells me I'm being targeted? Guess I will use Opera. I like it. Thank you for your time & help.